# Can raft ordering service have consenter set?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, raft

Our DLT network requires high TPS and splitting ordering service into 3 different locations will have a negative impact on the performance as per raft protocol all ordering nodes(deployed on different locations) will take part in consensus. So we have below questions related to this:

1. Can we specify the consenter set(contains orderer node only from the main location) in raft ordering service so that ordering service will take a consensus from only the orderer node present in the consenter set?
2. Can we have an orderer leader is chosen from the consenter set(contains orderer node only from the main location)?
3. Do other orderer nodes than the consenter set do not take active participation in consensus?

Definition for consenter set is referred from https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/orderer/ordering_service.html
Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can define any set of consenters for each channel, but every consenter must be a part of the system channel.
2. You cannot control the leader of the consenter set, it is chosen by the protocol only.
3. Yes, if you have, say, `n` orderer nodes in the network, you can define that only `k<n` of them will be used for a given channel.

Having said that, Raft supports pipelining of blocks, so even if you deploy the nodes in different parts of the world, you would still have decent throughput.